# MAAS JUJU still get bad archive mirror

Tags: juju, maas

I'm trying to install maas nodes by using the PXE BOOT method. I follow the maas wiki tutorial step by step. I get all node ready and juju bootstrap was great :)

But I still get "bad archive mirror" on all nodes :(

I can ping archive.ubuntu.com and I get is alive! from all nodes.

Her is my config:

- 3 PCs (nodes)
- 1 switch
- 1 Ubuntu Desktop as MAAS Server with NAT (LAN-Card and WLAN-CARD )

sorry about my broken english. I am writing from Germany

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

After changing the Management to Manage DHCP and DNS in the "Edit Cluster Interface" each node can reach the internet.

Here is the configuration:
MAAS-Web-UI -> Settings -> Cluster controllers -> Edit Cluster Controller -> edit Interfaces -> Management -> changin it from Manage DHCP to  Manage DHCP and DNS